# How to Reorder/Move certain elements in an array to the initial indexes based on a Boolean variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Is there any way to filter this below array such that, the objects which has isTop:true has to be on the initial indexes of the array.
Actual Array:

```
[{id:'1',name:'CAR',isTop:false},
{id:'2',name:'BIKE',isTop:true},
{id:'3',name:'TRUCK',isTop:false},
{id:'4',name:'BUS',isTop:false},
{id:'5',name:'VAN',isTop:true},
{id:'6',name:'TRAIN',isTop:false}]
```

Result Array I need:

```
[{id:'2',name:'BIKE',isTop:true},
{id:'5',name:'VAN',isTop:true},
{id:'3',name:'TRUCK',isTop:false},
{id:'4',name:'BUS',isTop:false},
{id:'1',name:'CAR',isTop:false},
{id:'6',name:'TRAIN',isTop:false}]
```

Comment: That's a simple matter of sorting the array, with the `isTop` property of each object as the sort key, sorting in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array.sort`.

In my solution, you could use the idea of `true - false = 1` to do the sort

```js
let array = [{id:'1',name:'CAR',isTop:false},
{id:'2',name:'BIKE',isTop:true},
{id:'3',name:'TRUCK',isTop:false},
{id:'4',name:'BUS',isTop:false},
{id:'5',name:'VAN',isTop:true},
{id:'6',name:'TRAIN',isTop:false}]
    
    array.sort((x, y) =>(y.isTop-x.isTop))
    console.log(array)
```